# How to design a resource association problem in Java

Tags: java, resources, modeling, allocation

I have the following modeling problem:

as an exercise, I need to model a system that allocates units (police cars/fire trucks) to a specific emergency `(fire/robbery/...)`. Therefore an emergency needs to say how many units it needs (for instance 2 fire trucks and 3 ambulances). Of course, these units need to be assigned to that emergency. I've modeled this as two abstract classes: Emergency and Unit with the real units and emergencies that inherit these classes.

Is there an elegant design so the emergency can tell in a generic way which units it needs (additional types of units and emergencies are expected)?

The programming language is Java.

I know this is probably one of the standard design patterns, but I'm quite new to these design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options with this. Some of the patterns that come to mind are Observer, Chain of Responsibility, and Visitor. However, a lot of non-pattern solutions seem reasonable too. Don't be hypnotized into using patterns all the time.

That being said, a combination of patterns will probably be the best solution. Create a higher level class, some sort of a Director. Allow the Director to observe the Emergencies, using the Observer pattern. When the Director receives a work request, it goes to an [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) and modifies the Emergency as it sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

What about good ol' Java interface?

```
public interface HasEmergency {
    public UnitType responderUnit();
    public int numberOfUnitsNeeded();
}

public abstract class Resource implements HasEmergency {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work, only the emergency knows how much resources are needed, For instance when a fire is large it needs 3 fire trucks, otherwise 1. So only the emergency can publish a list. In need a system that can dispatch resources to the emergency (like a firetruck/ambulance/...). But I want to make it generic so I can add another type of units (for example an army unit).